# TypeError: must provide a stream to wrap

Tags: python, pipenv

When I type `pipenv shell` in my command line to activate virtual environment I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts\pipenv.exe\__main_
_.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\__ini
t__.py", line 41, in <module>
    stdout = get_text_stream("stdout")
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendo
r\vistir\misc.py", line 1191, in get_text_stream
    return get_wrapped_stream(sys_stream, encoding)
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pipenv\vendo
r\vistir\misc.py", line 969, in get_wrapped_stream
    raise TypeError("must provide a stream to wrap")
TypeError: must provide a stream to wrap
```

if you know how to overcome this error, please answer. Thank you.

Comment: Can you [edit] to provide more details about your env? On which kind of terminal/console are you running this? Is this standard Windows cmd or powershell? Whar version of pipenv do you have?

Comment: When I close the command line the problem is solved. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think what your problem is, that you're missing stdout. I've had a similar problem with a script that was invoked from KDE. It kind of failed with a similar error message.

My fix for the moment was to simply redirect the stdout to `/dev/null`. I assume that this won't quite work, considering you are working from within a shell that should have stdin/stout. You might have to reconsider your working environment. But just a guess.